# Adding times, calculate total time

Tags: java, jodatime

I try to calculate a List with times. But using LocalTime from Joda Time I can only get a 24 hours.

What is the right class to use to get e.g. 34hours 20minutes 14 seconds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be look for [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html):

> A period in Joda-Time represents a period of time defined in terms of fields, for example, 3 years 5 months 2 days and 7 hours. This differs from a duration in that it is inexact in terms of milliseconds. A period can only be resolved to an exact number of milliseconds by specifying the instant (including chronology and time zone) it is relative to.

Comment: Thanks, using Period and the normalizedStandard method solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add times, so you can tell how many hours/seconds... are in between, you would maybe be better off if you use plain miliseconds calculations, add all the miliseconds and then subsrtact the miliseconds from your first time, and there you are, you have the span in miliseconds...